# How to calculate the mean value of a List of KeyValuePair using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List:

```
List<KeyValuePair<double, double>> MyList
```

I want to calculate the mean value for all the **keys** in the list, and for all the **values** in the list.

I'm now doing it this way:

```
foreach (var item in MyList)
{
    sumA += item.Key;
    sumB += item.Value;
}

KeysMean = sumA / MyList.Count;
ValuesMean = sumB / MyList.Count;
```

But if it's possible doing the same thing using LINQ I'd like to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Enumerable.Average](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Average__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Nullable_System_Double___) for calculating the average/mean.

```
var KeysMean = MyList.Average(x=>x.Key); 
var ValuesMean = MyList.Average(x=>x.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

[@AnuViswan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366089/150605) contains the straightforward approach of using the [`Enumerable.Average()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average) method, though notice it requires enumerating `MyList` once for each average being computed.  To compute both averages in one enumeration you can use the [`Enumerable.Aggregate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) method...

```cs
var result = MyList.Aggregate(
    new {
        KeysSum = 0D,
        ValuesSum = 0D
    },
    (accumulated, currentPair) => new {
        KeysSum = accumulated.KeysSum + currentPair.Key,
        ValuesSum = accumulated.ValuesSum + currentPair.Value
    },
    accumulated => new {
        KeysMean = accumulated.KeysSum / MyList.Count,
        ValuesMean = accumulated.ValuesSum / MyList.Count
    }
);
// Use result.KeysMean...
// Use result.ValuesMean...
```

The first parameter is the seed; the starting value for our sum.  Here I create an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) with a property to store each sum being computed.

The second parameter is a delegate that takes two parameters - the aggregated value up to this point, and the current element in the enumeration - and returns the value to be passed with the next element in the enumeration.  Here I add each property being summed to the ongoing sum.

The third parameter transforms the final value.  After all elements have been enumerated this delegate receives the aggregated value we use to return whatever we want; in this case a new object that uses each sum property to calculate an average property.

There is another overload that's a little less code but may be more confusing in this usage...

```cs
KeyValuePair<double, double> sumPair = MyList.Aggregate(
    (accumulatedPair, currentPair) => new KeyValuePair<double, double>(
        accumulatedPair.Key + currentPair.Key,
        accumulatedPair.Value + currentPair.Value
    )
);
double KeysMean = sumPair.Key / MyList.Count;
double ValuesMean = sumPair.Value / MyList.Count;
```

This omits the seed parameter and just uses the first element of the enumeration in its place.  That works fine since we're computing sums, but it means we have to use [`KeyValuePair<double, double>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2) instances to store the intermediate and final sums, which is...strange.  Essentially we're just using them as containers for two `double` values stored in misnamed properties.

There is also no parameter to perform the final transformation from sums to averages, so we need to do that after [`Aggregate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) returns.

---

Benchmarking the methods presented in the answers against the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) loop in the question, I got these results...

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.0, OS=Windows 10.0.18363
Intel Core i7 CPU 860 2.80GHz (Nehalem), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.1.100
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.56402, CoreFX 4.700.19.56404), X64 RyuJIT
  Job-VDYKPE : .NET Framework 4.8 (4.8.4042.0), X64 RyuJIT
  Job-ALYEQL : .NET Core 3.1.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.56402, CoreFX 4.700.19.56404), X64 RyuJIT


|                                        Method |       Runtime | ListLength |              Mean |            Error |            StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD |
|---------------------------------------------- |-------------- |----------- |------------------:|-----------------:|------------------:|------:|--------:|
|                                   ForeachLoop |      .NET 4.8 |         10 |          76.13 ns |         1.131 ns |          1.058 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 |
|                                   LinqAverage |      .NET 4.8 |         10 |         627.03 ns |        15.446 ns |         14.448 ns |  8.24 |    0.23 |
|                      LinqAggregate_Accumulate |      .NET 4.8 |         10 |         163.40 ns |         1.686 ns |          1.577 ns |  2.15 |    0.04 |
|  LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Anonymous |      .NET 4.8 |         10 |         283.08 ns |         3.309 ns |          3.095 ns |  3.72 |    0.09 |
|      LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Tuple |      .NET 4.8 |         10 |         280.78 ns |         2.207 ns |          2.064 ns |  3.69 |    0.06 |
| LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_ValueTuple |      .NET 4.8 |         10 |         190.28 ns |         1.643 ns |          1.537 ns |  2.50 |    0.05 |
|                                               |               |            |                   |                  |                   |       |         |
|                                   ForeachLoop | .NET Core 3.1 |         10 |          71.46 ns |         0.153 ns |          0.128 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 |
|                                   LinqAverage | .NET Core 3.1 |         10 |         325.56 ns |         2.296 ns |          1.917 ns |  4.56 |    0.03 |
|                      LinqAggregate_Accumulate | .NET Core 3.1 |         10 |         149.84 ns |         0.189 ns |          0.158 ns |  2.10 |    0.00 |
|  LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Anonymous | .NET Core 3.1 |         10 |         296.62 ns |         1.691 ns |          1.582 ns |  4.15 |    0.02 |
|      LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Tuple | .NET Core 3.1 |         10 |         297.98 ns |         0.822 ns |          0.729 ns |  4.17 |    0.02 |
| LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_ValueTuple | .NET Core 3.1 |         10 |         173.39 ns |         1.623 ns |          1.518 ns |  2.42 |    0.02 |
|                                               |               |            |                   |                  |                   |       |         |
|                                   ForeachLoop |      .NET 4.8 |      10000 |      42,353.23 ns |       366.061 ns |        342.414 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 |
|                                   LinqAverage |      .NET 4.8 |      10000 |     397,256.97 ns |       870.507 ns |        679.635 ns |  9.37 |    0.09 |
|                      LinqAggregate_Accumulate |      .NET 4.8 |      10000 |     117,508.08 ns |     1,121.723 ns |      1,049.260 ns |  2.77 |    0.03 |
|  LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Anonymous |      .NET 4.8 |      10000 |     198,428.49 ns |     1,963.924 ns |      1,837.056 ns |  4.69 |    0.06 |
|      LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Tuple |      .NET 4.8 |      10000 |     201,231.39 ns |     1,537.753 ns |      1,438.415 ns |  4.75 |    0.05 |
| LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_ValueTuple |      .NET 4.8 |      10000 |     118,744.85 ns |       898.424 ns |        840.386 ns |  2.80 |    0.04 |
|                                               |               |            |                   |                  |                   |       |         |
|                                   ForeachLoop | .NET Core 3.1 |      10000 |      43,877.26 ns |        83.330 ns |         65.058 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 |
|                                   LinqAverage | .NET Core 3.1 |      10000 |     264,375.27 ns |     1,886.030 ns |      1,764.194 ns |  6.03 |    0.03 |
|                      LinqAggregate_Accumulate | .NET Core 3.1 |      10000 |     143,461.54 ns |       373.136 ns |        311.585 ns |  3.27 |    0.01 |
|  LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Anonymous | .NET Core 3.1 |      10000 |     229,068.61 ns |     2,115.815 ns |      1,979.135 ns |  5.21 |    0.04 |
|      LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Tuple | .NET Core 3.1 |      10000 |     226,882.21 ns |       465.347 ns |        412.518 ns |  5.17 |    0.01 |
| LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_ValueTuple | .NET Core 3.1 |      10000 |     119,436.99 ns |     1,115.281 ns |      1,043.235 ns |  2.72 |    0.03 |
|                                               |               |            |                   |                  |                   |       |         |
|                                   ForeachLoop |      .NET 4.8 |   10000000 |  45,171,088.46 ns |   601,307.078 ns |    502,118.644 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 |
|                                   LinqAverage |      .NET 4.8 |   10000000 | 465,869,087.50 ns | 9,144,925.184 ns | 16,255,095.222 ns | 10.50 |    0.38 |
|                      LinqAggregate_Accumulate |      .NET 4.8 |   10000000 | 115,428,201.33 ns |   261,893.934 ns |    244,975.748 ns |  2.56 |    0.03 |
|  LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Anonymous |      .NET 4.8 |   10000000 | 201,173,316.67 ns |   688,538.711 ns |    610,371.633 ns |  4.46 |    0.06 |
|      LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Tuple |      .NET 4.8 |   10000000 | 204,807,197.78 ns | 2,039,290.108 ns |  1,907,553.233 ns |  4.53 |    0.06 |
| LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_ValueTuple |      .NET 4.8 |   10000000 | 123,259,086.67 ns | 1,585,820.455 ns |  1,483,377.438 ns |  2.72 |    0.04 |
|                                               |               |            |                   |                  |                   |       |         |
|                                   ForeachLoop | .NET Core 3.1 |   10000000 |  44,861,125.64 ns |    89,622.978 ns |     74,839.246 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 |
|                                   LinqAverage | .NET Core 3.1 |   10000000 | 267,218,486.67 ns |   721,661.661 ns |    675,042.766 ns |  5.96 |    0.02 |
|                      LinqAggregate_Accumulate | .NET Core 3.1 |   10000000 | 148,392,786.67 ns | 1,569,628.109 ns |  1,468,231.107 ns |  3.31 |    0.04 |
|  LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Anonymous | .NET Core 3.1 |   10000000 | 229,924,633.33 ns | 3,235,373.921 ns |  3,026,370.773 ns |  5.13 |    0.07 |
|      LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Tuple | .NET Core 3.1 |   10000000 | 229,694,275.00 ns | 2,913,179.002 ns |  2,274,418.544 ns |  5.12 |    0.05 |
| LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_ValueTuple | .NET Core 3.1 |   10000000 | 119,003,596.67 ns |   170,037.184 ns |    132,753.849 ns |  2.65 |    0.01 |
```

The results show that...

- [`Enumerable.Average()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average) is 2x-4x as slow as [`Enumerable.Aggregate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate), certainly in part because it has to enumerate the list twice.
- The one-parameter overload of [`Enumerable.Aggregate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) has comparable performance to the three-parameter overload when the latter is used with [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple)s.  Using the three-parameter overload with an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) or [`Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.tuple) is 70% slower (or worse) than using [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple).
- The [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) loop is 2.5x as fast as the next fastest solution, with code slightly longer than and about as simple as [`Enumerable.Average()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average).

Here is the benchmarking code I used, which makes use of the [`BenchmarkDotNet` library](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/)...

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;

namespace SO59366077
{
    [SimpleJob(BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs.RuntimeMoniker.NetCoreApp31)]
    [SimpleJob(BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs.RuntimeMoniker.Net48)]
    public class Benchmark
    {
        const int TemplateDataStart = 1;
        const int TemplateDataCount = 100;
        static readonly IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>> TemplateData = Array.AsReadOnly(
            Enumerable.Range(0, TemplateDataCount)
                .Select(
                    offset => new KeyValuePair<double, double>(
                        TemplateDataStart + offset,                           // From Min..Max
                        -(TemplateDataStart + TemplateDataCount - 1) + offset // From -Max..-Min
                    )
                ).ToArray()
        );

        List<KeyValuePair<double, double>> MyList
        {
            get;
        } = new List<KeyValuePair<double, double>>();

        double KeysMean
        {
            get; set;
        }

        double ValuesMean
        {
            get; set;
        }

        [Params(10, 10_000, 10_000_000)]
        public int ListLength;

        [GlobalSetup()]
        public void GlobalSetup()
        {
            int fullTemplateCount = ListLength / TemplateDataCount;
            int partialTemplateLength = ListLength % TemplateDataCount;
            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<double, double>> data = Enumerable.Range(1, fullTemplateCount)
                .SelectMany(i => TemplateData)
                .Concat(
                    TemplateData.Take(partialTemplateLength)
                );

            MyList.AddRange(data);
        }

        [GlobalCleanup()]
        public void GlobalCleanup()
        {
            MyList.Clear();
        }

        // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/59366077
        [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
        public void ForeachLoop()
        {
            double sumA = 0D;
            double sumB = 0D;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<double, double> item in MyList)
            {
                sumA += item.Key;
                sumB += item.Value;
            }

            KeysMean = sumA / MyList.Count;
            ValuesMean = sumB / MyList.Count;
        }

        // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366089
        [Benchmark()]
        public void LinqAverage()
        {
            KeysMean = MyList.Average(x => x.Key);
            ValuesMean = MyList.Average(x => x.Value);
        }

        // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366439
        [Benchmark()]
        public void LinqAggregate_Accumulate()
        {
            KeyValuePair<double, double> sumPair = MyList.Aggregate(
                (accumulatedPair, currentPair) => new KeyValuePair<double, double>(
                    accumulatedPair.Key + currentPair.Key,
                    accumulatedPair.Value + currentPair.Value
                )
            );

            KeysMean = sumPair.Key / MyList.Count;
            ValuesMean = sumPair.Value / MyList.Count;
        }

        // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366439
        [Benchmark()]
        public void LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Anonymous()
        {
            var result = MyList.Aggregate(
                new {
                    KeysSum = 0D,
                    ValuesSum = 0D
                },
                (accumulated, currentPair) => new {
                    KeysSum = accumulated.KeysSum + currentPair.Key,
                    ValuesSum = accumulated.ValuesSum + currentPair.Value
                },
                accumulated => new {
                    KeysMean = accumulated.KeysSum / MyList.Count,
                    ValuesMean = accumulated.ValuesSum / MyList.Count
                }
            );
        }

        // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366439
        [Benchmark()]
        public void LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_Tuple()
        {
            var result = MyList.Aggregate(
                Tuple.Create(0D, 0D),
                (accumulated, currentPair) => Tuple.Create(
                    accumulated.Item1 + currentPair.Key,
                    accumulated.Item2 + currentPair.Value
                ),
                accumulated => Tuple.Create(
                    accumulated.Item1 / MyList.Count,
                    accumulated.Item2 / MyList.Count
                )
            );

            KeysMean = result.Item1;
            ValuesMean = result.Item2;
        }

        // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366439
        [Benchmark()]
        public void LinqAggregate_SeedAccumulateSelect_ValueTuple()
        {
            (KeysMean, ValuesMean) = MyList.Aggregate(
                (KeysSum: 0D, ValuesSum: 0D),
                (accumulated, currentPair) => (
                    KeysSum: accumulated.KeysSum + currentPair.Key,
                    ValuesSum: accumulated.ValuesSum + currentPair.Value
                ),
                accumulated => (
                    KeysMean: accumulated.KeysSum / MyList.Count,
                    ValuesMean: accumulated.ValuesSum / MyList.Count
                )
            );
        }

        static void Main()
        {
#if DEBUG
            Benchmark benchmark = new Benchmark() {
                ListLength = 500
            };

            benchmark.GlobalSetup();

            IEnumerable<System.Reflection.MethodInfo> benchmarkMethods = benchmark.GetType().GetMethods()
                .Where(method => method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BenchmarkAttribute), false).Any());
            var results = benchmarkMethods.Select(
                method => {
                    method.Invoke(benchmark, null);

                    return new {
                        MethodName = method.Name,
                        KeysMean = benchmark.KeysMean,
                        ValuesMean = benchmark.ValuesMean
                    };
                }
            ).ToArray();

            // Ensure all benchmark methods yield the same value for KeysMean
            foreach (var keysMeanValueGroup in results.GroupBy(result => result.KeysMean))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  KeysMean == {keysMeanValueGroup.Key}");
                foreach (var result in keysMeanValueGroup)
                    Console.WriteLine($"\t{result.MethodName}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // Ensure all benchmark methods yield the same value for ValuesMean
            foreach (var valuesMeanValueGroup in results.GroupBy(result => result.ValuesMean))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ValuesMean == {valuesMeanValueGroup.Key}");
                foreach (var result in valuesMeanValueGroup)
                    Console.WriteLine($"\t{result.MethodName}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            benchmark.GlobalCleanup();
#else
            BenchmarkDotNet.Running.BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmark>();
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be interesting to offer a timing comparison between the two methods in each answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity Suggest and ye shall pique my curiosity enough to update my answer with exactly that.